# What is the best way to CRUD data in SQL database into SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-server, event-receivers, content-database, external-list

In Sharepoint site, I have a list, it will display data from the table in SQL database.

When user insert, update or delete item in this list, the SQL database will be changed too. The change is one way: from SharePoint to SQL.

I tried the Event Receiver and also tried the External Content type, but each of them have many cons.

So, do we have any other suggestion to automatically update data from SharePoint list into the SQL database when having change in SharePoint list item ?

Answer (score 1):

BCS external content types and lists are the only OOTB way of surfacing the external data as per SharePoint guidelines. But you can always build your own solution in .Net on top of SharePoint.

Comment: Yes, I try this, but as I said, the BCS has some cons with not match my requirement. So I want to implement this project by another way. Do you have any suggestion to build the solution to connect them ? I also try the Event Receiver to CRUD data in SP list, but I'd like to find the best way.

Comment: i totally agree that BCS has its own limitations w.r.to SharePoint. But you haven't stated your requirements in the question so i can not suggest the best approach. pls try to elaborate your requirement then i am sure you can get a very specific answer. if your schema or relationships are so complex then you should try creating own .net class library and you can still use via BCS to leverage that.

Comment: Hi. I've just updated my question. My question is "do we have other way to update data from SP list into SQL database without using ER and External list ?"

Answer (score 0):

Create external content type(s) using BCS and create list using that external content type. The complete SQL table schema and data will be fetched to list. And you can create CRUD operations on them using SharePoint.

For more, refer to : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683749/Implementing-Business-Data-Connectivity-in-SharePo

Comment: Do we have the other solution for my project ?